# Rails Grapql has_many Connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, graphql

Im playing with graphQL and am having an issue pulling a data set that is a `has_many :trough` connection.

the error im getting in the consol is :
Started

```
POST "/graphql" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-25 19:28:24 -0400
Processing by GraphqlController#execute as */*
  Parameters: {"query"=>"query{\n  items{\n    id\n    title\n    collections{\n      id\n    }\n  }\n}", "variables"=>nil, "graphql"=>{"query"=>"query{\n  items{\n    id\n    title\n    collections{\n      id\n    }\n  }\n}", "variables"=>nil}}
  Item Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items`
  Collection Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `collections`.* FROM `collections` INNER JOIN `collection_item_crosses` ON `collections`.`id` = `collection_item_crosses`.`collection_id` WHERE `collection_item_crosses`.`item_id` = 1 LIMIT 11
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 79ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)



  CACHE Collection Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `collections`.* FROM `collections` INNER JOIN `collection_item_crosses` ON `collections`.`id` = `collection_item_crosses`.`collection_id` WHERE `collection_item_crosses`.`item_id` = 1 LIMIT 11  [["item_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Collection::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f6a38317d98>
Did you mean?  ids):

app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:12:in `execute'
```

my query looks like:

```
query{
  items{
    id
    title
    collections{
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I can confirm that the query does return data as i would expect but i have no idea what the undefined method error is referring to.

Collection type:

```
Types::CollectionType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Collection'

  field :id, !types.Int
  field :collection_name, !types.String
  field :collection_description, types.String
  field :items, -> { Types::ItemType }
  field :collectionItems, -> { Types::CollectionItemCrossType }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`:items` field is a collection. So declaration should look like:

```
Types::CollectionType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Collection'

  field :items, !types[Types::ItemType]
  field :collectionItems, !types[Types::CollectionItemCrossType]
end
```

`!types[]` stands for `GraphQL::ListType` of any other type.